# Pass function with parameters when submitting a form

Tags: javascript

I have a form that is basically a multiple choice quiz.  I would like to run a javascript function once the submit button has been clicked.  This function has two parameters: formID and answerID

```
<form id="Question1" onsubmit="multipleChoice(formID,answerID)">    
    <fieldset>
          <input type = "radio"
                 name = "Question1"
                 id = "Question1-a"
                 value = "answer 1" />
          <label for = "Question1-a">A&#41; answer 1</label>
          <br>
          .... other possible answers
      </fieldset> 
      <button type="submit">Submit</button> <!-- on submit, return the form ID and the answer ID that the user chose (e.g., (Question1,Question1-a)) -->
</form>
```

I would like to pull the ID for the answer that the user is submitting and put it in the second parameter and the ID for the form and put it in the first parameter. Is this possible using no php and only javascript/jquery?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3303064/pass-javascript-variables-to-form-input-fields-as-onsubmit-href-link

Comment: This is not appear to be the same thing at all.

Comment: The idea is to send a reference to the `form` by passing `this` and get all details from the reference to `form`

Comment: I understand that for the formID but how would I retrieve the answer that the user selected? They would be selecting one of several radio buttons.

Comment: Nevermind. I have found what I needed using your suggestion and help. Thank you very much sabithpocker!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/b1p0r8gu/

Comment: Thank you very much, sabithpocker. You were extremely helpful.